# Set-WebConfigurationProperty fails?

Tags: powershell, iis

I can successfully use the following cmdlet to setup the machine key in a config file:

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty 'system.web/machineKey' -PSPath "IIS:\sites\mysite" -name validationKey -value $validationKey`

On another web site, the system.web is located below a "location" tag like below:

```
<configuration>
 <location path=".">
  <system.web>
   <!-- machine key should come here -->
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

The following command fails to set the machine key in this case :

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty 'location[@path="."]/system.web/machineKey' -PSPath "IIS:\sites\mysite" -name validationKey -value $validationKey`

Error is :

Target configuration object 'location[@path="."]/system.web/machineKey is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/mysite'

Comment: Not sure on the use of the Set-WebConfigurationProperty cmdlet, but it looks like it's using xPath to specify the location, which i think would be system.web/machineKey/location[@path="."] in your example

Comment: Well, yes, it's using XPath indeed. I tried your proposal without success. But as the system.web is located below the "location" tag, I would expect to specify first the location tag with the attribute and then system.web and then my machineKey tag. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the -Filter parameter is supposed to work ???